# Android Mapview MyLocationOverlay Always drawn on top

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview, mylocationoverlay

I have a mapview, with the MyLocationOverlay, and other overlays. MyLocationOverlay is drawn under the other overlays, I want it on top. How can I change that? Is there any option to sort the overlays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The z-index of your layers depends on the order you added these layer. So add your MyLocationOverlay last.